# TFS2012 - Troubleshooting MSBuild arguments to set up automated deployment

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy, iis-8, automated-deployment

We are trying to set up automated deploys through TFS 2012 via MSBuild and MSDeploy but we are recieving a timeout when our production server attempts to deploy to the development server. All relevant ports have been opened, the deployment tools and services have been installed and started, the only evidence of an error we have to go on is a log file which came from the development server's IIS web management log folder, it is displaying a 404 when a deploy is attempted.

MSBuild arguments:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True
/p:UserName=*****
/p:Password=*****
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True
/p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish
/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC
/p:MSDeployServiceUrl=http://*******:8172/msdeploy.axd
/p:DeployIISAppPath="DeployTest"
```

Visual Studio build error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets (4377): Web deployment task failed. (Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'http://****:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=Default Web Site'.)

Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'http://****:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=Default Web Site'.
The operation has timed out
```

Comment: So the build is going fine then if I understand your question correctly and it has just todo with the deploy? So you have already everything in a `drop folder` that is configured in your `build definition`?

Comment: Yes, everything is building fine, the drop folder is located on the production server. When it attempts to deploy to the development server the error occurs, I've updated my post with the error message I receive from visual studio

Comment: Is there a firewall on the remote host where you want to deploy your application to? If so, turn it of and try again. Maybe it is blocking it.

Comment: Both firewalls have been taken down during a test build-deploy so it is not a firewall issue

Comment: It looks like msdeploy can't reach the target server.  I suggest that you try msdeploy command-line utility to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Firewall issues have been ruled out; we have opened all relevant ports on both production and development servers for deployment testing and still the same result is returned.